# Wash Sale Period Confusion

Tags: wash-sale

I am a bit confused by the language in the Wash Sale regulations regarding the purchase of the same security 30 days *before* or after.

All the explanations that I read seem to agree that divesting of a security in December and not repurchasing for 31 days next January allow you to take the loss in the same tax year, regardless of what was done during the year.  I'm just a little paranoid due to the language also barring purchase of the same instrument 30 days BEFORE the sale.  Does that include the purchase of the stock you sold?

Example: suppose that I sold AAPL for a loss on Dec. 1, then repurchased on Dec. 10 and finally sold it all out on Dec. 15.  Assuming I don't repurchase for 31 days (Jan 15 or later) my understanding is that I can claim the final loss on the current year.  Or would it be denied since my purchase on Dec. 10 (5 days before the final sale) is obviously the same as what I sold on the 15th since that's the very stock I sold.  I hope I'm overthinking this since no source seems to mention that possibility.

Comment: @user124308 - the linked article is nearly identical to your question. Closing this one as a duplicate. Members here tend to know what questions are pretty common, and closing is not considered a negative by any means.